# Difference between "data dependence graph", "data dependency graph", and "data flow graph"

Tags: terminology, programming-languages, data-flow-analysis

Is there a difference between a "data dependence graph" and a "data dependency graph"? I have seen both terms - sometimes used interchangeably sometimes not.

To make things even more complicated, a "data dependency graph" is sometimes also called a "data flow graph" (see e.g. [here](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~amaral/courses/429/webslides/Topic8-ILP-dynamic/sld009.htm)).

The term "data dependence graph" is, for example, used on the second slide [here](https://students.cs.byu.edu/~cs486ta/live-lectures/GeorgiaTech04-byu-live.pdf).

If there is a difference, could someone give an example of each graph type?
If there is no difference, why the two different terms?

Comment: Many things have many different terms...

Comment: So these terms all refer to the same thing ?

Comment: Probably. This can just be a "lost in translation". But I don't know for certain, and I've definitely seen cases where authors hid actual differences in such small differences.

Comment: I am not so sure - especially for the "data flow graph". There are different kinds of data dependencies, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dependency. Does the data flow graph include all of them? I don't think so. But for a "data dependency graph" I don't know.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science Stack Exchange. Please read
http://cs.stackexchange.com/tour, if you have not yet done so. Have you done some search to find differences, or definitions? What about wikipedia? What did you find?

Comment: @babou I give example links for definitions in my post.

Comment: I noticed. But if you search the web, there are document that talk of both dependence graph and data flow graph.  So there is a chance that they differ and that these document may have the info. I did not read them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Dependence* and *dependency* are interchangeable terms.  In my experience, *dependency* (with a "y") is more common.  In my own writing I try to consistently use *dependence* (without a "y") for aesthetic reasons (I think it sounds better).  If you look at a dictionary you'll see that the two words are *almost* synonyms.  The only difference I'm aware of is that *dependency* (with a "y") means something specific in the field of political science (it means a territory that is controlled, or owned, by some other sovereign state.)  (This leads to my aesthetic dislike: the political dependency relation is asymmetric, while the dependence relation we use in program analysis is not.)

There are lots of minor variations between dependence graphs.  The dependences can be *must* dependences ("*a* always depends on *b*") or *may* dependences ("*a* could depend on *b*").  The graph might show *control dependences* in addition to data dependences (in which case it will be called a *program dependence graph*, and almost certainly will not be called a *data-flow graph*).  The dependence graph might or might not be superimposed on top of a *control-flow graph*.

Whether something is called a *dependenc(e/y)* graph or *data-flow* graph is pretty much also a matter of taste.  I try to avoid *data-flow graph* in my own writing, unless I am specifically talking about someone else's research and they have used the term *data-flow graph*.  (In particular, research on [Dataflow computer architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_architecture).)

Comment: So, an author *may* elect to distinguish different flavors of the same thing by e vs y? A bad choice, clearly. Can we confirm the OP does not see such an instance?

Comment: @Raphael What do you mean by your last sentence?

Comment: @Wandering Logic: I noticed you were talking about **dependenc(e/y) graphs** but leave out the **data**. Did you do this on purpose, e.g. to keep things short, or because you do not see a difference between a "dependenc(e/y) graph" and a "data dependenc(e/y) graph because every "data dependenc(e/y) graph" is a "dependenc(e/y) graph"?

Comment: @stackoverflowwww: Every data dependenc(e/y) graph is a dependenc(e/y) graph.

Comment: @WanderingLogic  Ok, thanks for the clarification. But isn't a data flow graph s. th. different? Is a data flow graph a dependence graph? I am unsure if it is really only a matter of taste whether to use the term data flow graph or dependency graph as there are different kind of dependencies and "flow" is only one of them. See also my comment with the link to different kind of data dependencies.

Comment: A _data-flow graph_ is definitely a kind of dependence graph.  It's a kind of dependence graph that includes only data flow dependences, I guess.  Personally, I don't think I'd ever call a dependence graph that included anti-, output-, input-, or control-dependences a _data_ dependence graph.